# How to Call guided decision table from java?

Tags: java, drools, drools-guvnor

```
KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();

KieResources resources = ks.getResources();


String url = messageSource.getMessage("merchant.drool.engine.url", null, Locale.US);
UrlResource urlResource = (UrlResource) resources.newUrlResource(url);
urlResource.setUsername(messageSource.getMessage("merchant.drool.engin.username", null, Locale.US));
urlResource.setPassword(messageSource.getMessage("merchant.drool.engin.password", null, Locale.US));
urlResource.setBasicAuthentication(messageSource.getMessage("merchant.drool.engin.basicauth", null, Locale.US));

logger.info("DTR BATCH: Downloading... kie jar started.");

InputStream stream = urlResource.getInputStream();

KieRepository repo = ks.getRepository();
KieModule k = repo.addKieModule(resources.newInputStreamResource(stream));
KieContainer kieContainer = ks.newKieContainer(k.getReleaseId());

KieScanner kieScanner = ks.newKieScanner(kieContainer);
kieScanner.start(5000L);

KieSession kSession = kieKontainer.newKieSession();

MyDataObject mObj = new MyDataObject();
kSession.insert(mObj);
System.out.println("Fired rules: " + kSession.fireAllRules());
```

We have created a guided decision table at the drool engine side. I am calling the decision table(gdst) from java code. Above code is executing without any error, but It's not updating data in mObj. Drool is returning the same object that we are passing.

Comment: If your rules don't change the inserted `MyDataObject` it will not change. If you have rules changing a  `MyDataObject` they aren't fired. -- What is the constructor code of ` MyDataObject` and what is the code of the rules supposed to fire and and change such an object?

Comment: Guided rule is updating the object, but If I create decision table(gdst), It's not updating the object. I have made default constructor. Can you share the example code to call drool decision table(gdst) from java.

Answer (score 0):

In this link [1] is shown how to build `KieBase` from GDST. Then you are just one step from obtaining `KieSession` like:

```
kieBase.newKiewSession();
```

[1]
https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/blob/master/drools-workbench-models/drools-workbench-models-guided-dtable/src/test/java/org/drools/workbench/models/guided/dtable/backend/GuidedDTableParsingIntegrationTest.java

Answer (score 0):

kSession.fireAllRules() method return int, i.e number of rules executed. To confirm if rule is executed or not you can print 'int' value after executing fireallrule method.

Answer (score 0):

Above code asked in the question is working fine, Just need to update maven dependencies.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
  <artifactId>kie-ci</artifactId>
  <version>6.5.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
    <artifactId>drools-workbench-models-guided-dtable</artifactId>
    <version>6.5.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
    <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.5.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```